# encryption in UWP cyclic redundency check

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10

I am making a security software which encrypt data using AES encryption
when I encrypt or decrypt using FileIO it works fine as all the bytes are read and fed to the encrypt function at once but that leads to problem for huge files as it loads a huge file into the ram.
So I used datareader and datawriter to load file partially and sent it to encrypt
but the problem is as I do this when I decrypt this file it throws cyclic redundancy error. I partially know the reason but don't know how to fix
here are my codes
New one using data reader and writer

```
public async void EncryptDecryptFileNew(StorageFile sourcefile, StorageFolder destinationfolder, string password, string username, bool IsEncrypt)
{
    passwordstring = AES_Encrypt(StringToBytes(password), username);
    if (sourcefile != null)
    {
        StorageFile sfile = null;
        bool isCompletedSuccesfully = false;
        try
        {
            if (StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.CheckAccess(sourcefile))
            {
                var properties = await sourcefile.GetBasicPropertiesAsync();
                string temp = destinationfolder.Path;
                StorageFolder sf = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(temp);
                sfile = await sf.CreateFileAsync(sourcefile.Name, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
                Debug.WriteLine(sourcefile.DisplayName + properties.Size, "FileStart");
                if (properties.Size > 0)
                {
                    using (Stream sstream = await sourcefile.OpenStreamForReadAsync())
                    {
                        using (DataReader sourceReader = new DataReader(sstream.AsInputStream()))
                        {
                            using (var dstream = await sfile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
                            {
                                using (var outputStream = dstream.GetOutputStreamAt(0))
                                {
                                    using (DataWriter dWriter = new DataWriter(outputStream))
                                    {
                                        byte[] f;
                                        for (ulong i = 0; i < (properties.Size / 64); i++)
                                        {
                                            await sourceReader.LoadAsync(64);
                                            if (IsEncrypt)
                                                f = AES_Encrypt(sourceReader.ReadBuffer(64).ToArray(), BytesToString(passwordstring));
                                            else
                                                f = AES_Decrypt(sourceReader.ReadBuffer(64).ToArray(), BytesToString(passwordstring));
                                            dWriter.WriteBytes(f);

                                        }
                                        uint remaining = (uint)properties.Size % 64;
                                        if ((remaining) != 0)
                                        {
                                            await sourceReader.LoadAsync(remaining);
                                            if (IsEncrypt)
                                                f = AES_Encrypt(sourceReader.ReadBuffer(remaining).ToArray(), BytesToString(passwordstring));
                                            else
                                                f = AES_Decrypt(sourceReader.ReadBuffer(remaining).ToArray(), BytesToString(passwordstring));
                                            dWriter.WriteBytes(f);
                                        }
                                        await dWriter.StoreAsync();

                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    isCompletedSuccesfully = true;
                    GC.Collect();
                }
                else
                    isCompletedSuccesfully = true;
                Debug.WriteLine(sourcefile.DisplayName, "FileEnd");
            }
        }
        catch (OutOfMemoryException y)
        {
            GC.Collect();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(e.Message, "Encryption File");
        }
        finally
        {
            System.GC.Collect();
            if (isCompletedSuccesfully)
            {
                if (totalSize != 0)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(sourcefile.DisplayName + " " + fileDictionary[sourcefile.Path] + " " + totalSize);
                    Percentage += fileDictionary[sourcefile.Path] / totalSize;
                }
                if (FEDD != null)
                    FEDD();
            }
            else
            {
                if (fileDictionary.Count != 0)

                {
                    if (sfile != null)
                    {
                        await sfile.DeleteAsync();
                    }
                    EncryptDecryptFileNew(sourcefile, destinationfolder, password, username, IsEncrypt);
                }
            }
            await Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
}
```

for encryption

```
public byte[] AES_Encrypt(byte[] input, string pass)
{
    SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider SAP = SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(SymmetricAlgorithmNames.AesEcbPkcs7);
    CryptographicKey AES;
    HashAlgorithmProvider HAP = HashAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(HashAlgorithmNames.Md5);
    CryptographicHash Hash_AES = HAP.CreateHash();
    try
    {
        IBuffer Buffer = CryptographicBuffer.CreateFromByteArray(input);
        byte[] encrypted;
        byte[] hash = new byte[32];
        Hash_AES.Append(CryptographicBuffer.CreateFromByteArray(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pass)));
        byte[] temp;
        CryptographicBuffer.CopyToByteArray(Hash_AES.GetValueAndReset(), out temp);
        Array.Copy(temp, 0, hash, 0, 16);
        Array.Copy(temp, 0, hash, 15, 16);
        AES = SAP.CreateSymmetricKey(CryptographicBuffer.CreateFromByteArray(hash));
        encrypted= (CryptographicEngine.Encrypt(AES, Buffer, null)).ToArray();
        //encrypted = CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToBase64String(CryptographicEngine.Encrypt(AES, Buffer, null));
        return encrypted;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message,"AES ENCRYPT");
        return null;
    }
}
```

for decryption

```
public byte[] AES_Decrypt(byte[] input, string pass)
{
    SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider SAP = SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(SymmetricAlgorithmNames.AesEcbPkcs7);
    CryptographicKey AES;
    HashAlgorithmProvider HAP = HashAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(HashAlgorithmNames.Md5);
    CryptographicHash Hash_AES = HAP.CreateHash();
    try
    {
        byte[] hash = new byte[32];
        Hash_AES.Append(CryptographicBuffer.CreateFromByteArray(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pass)));
        byte[] temp;
        CryptographicBuffer.CopyToByteArray(Hash_AES.GetValueAndReset(), out temp);
        Array.Copy(temp, 0, hash, 0, 16);
        Array.Copy(temp, 0, hash, 15, 16);
        AES = SAP.CreateSymmetricKey(CryptographicBuffer.CreateFromByteArray(hash));
        IBuffer Buffer = GetBufferFromBytes(input);
        byte[] Decrypted;
        CryptographicBuffer.CopyToByteArray(CryptographicEngine.Decrypt(AES, Buffer, null), out Decrypted);
        return Decrypted;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        return null;
    }
}
```

and the old one that worked

```
public async void EncryptDecryptFile(StorageFile sourcefile,StorageFolder destinationfolder,string password,string username,bool IsEncrypt)
{
    passwordstring = AES_Encrypt(StringToBytes(password), username);
    if (sourcefile != null)
    {
        StorageFile sfile=null;
        bool isCompletedSuccesfully = false;
        try
        {
            if (StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.CheckAccess(sourcefile))
            {
                var properties = await sourcefile.GetBasicPropertiesAsync();
                string temp = destinationfolder.Path;
                StorageFolder sf = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(temp);
                sfile = await sf.CreateFileAsync(sourcefile.Name, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
                Debug.WriteLine(sourcefile.DisplayName+properties.Size,"FileStart");
                if (properties.Size > 0)
                {
                    IBuffer buffer = await FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(sourcefile);
                    byte[] f = null;
                    Debug.WriteLine("tw1", sourcefile.Name);
                    GC.Collect();
                    if (IsEncrypt)
                        f = AES_Encrypt(buffer.ToArray(), BytesToString(passwordstring));
                    else
                        f = AES_Decrypt(buffer.ToArray(), BytesToString(passwordstring));
                    Debug.WriteLine("tw2", sourcefile.Name);
                    GC.Collect();
                    var rt = FileIO.WriteBufferAsync(sfile, GetBufferFromBytes(f));
                    rt.AsTask().Wait();
                    isCompletedSuccesfully = true;
                    GC.Collect();
                    Debug.WriteLine("tw3", sourcefile.Name);
                }
                else
                    isCompletedSuccesfully = true;
                Debug.WriteLine(sourcefile.DisplayName, "FileEnd");
            }
        }
        catch (OutOfMemoryException y)
        {
            GC.Collect();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(e.Message,"Encryption File");
        }
        finally
        {
            System.GC.Collect();
            if (isCompletedSuccesfully)
            {
                if (totalSize != 0)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(sourcefile.DisplayName + " " + fileDictionary[sourcefile.Path] + " " + totalSize);
                    Percentage += fileDictionary[sourcefile.Path] / totalSize;
                }
                if(FEDD!=null)
                FEDD();
            }
            else
            {
                if (fileDictionary.Count != 0)

                {
                    if (sfile != null)
                    {
                        await sfile.DeleteAsync();
                    }
                    EncryptDecryptFile(sourcefile, destinationfolder, password, username, IsEncrypt);
                }
            }
            await Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
}
```